# Authorization approach in microservice architecture

Tags: architecture, authorization, microservices

I am looking to solve an authorization issue in a microservice environment. I have a gateway service and 14 underlying microservices. I am using IdentityServer4 for authentication and resource authorization. I am then using policy based authorization within each individual service. This works fine for most scenarios but...

All microservices will require to check complex authorization rule for certain requests. Imagine Facebook checking if you and resource owner are a connection. This information can be provided by "connection service" I am deliberating how to best solve it thinking:

1: do this once at a gateway level. Let gateway call the "connection service" and make all services assume request is authorized for this specific scenario. This will make authorization move up from service level and will loose some flexibility but avoid duplication. Although not sure about giving gateway this extra responsibility

2: keep the authorization at a service level, let each microservice call the "connection service", this will create duplication and make the system quite a bit more chatty. Doesn't sound great

3: when connection changes let the "connection service" post a message on a topic that all other services subscribe to, let the services keep their own record of existing connections. The duplication sounds bad here but benefit would be that authorization is kept at a service level and there is a performance benefit as well - no latency.

Please let me know if there is a standard way to solve this for large architectures that I could emulate, or if there is a better way.

Comment: This is an interesting approach. That requirements first sound to me like a business requirement than a security one. On the other hand it sounds like a permission thing so it is some sort of authorization definitely. As far as I know there is no standard way of solving this problem. In order to judge your solutions we need more information like: in your system do you have a chain communication like service A-> service B->service C. What is the size of the "connections"? Can you somehow fetch these connection for a person before and send them to services as an attribute of token etc. ?

Comment: Thank you for a comment. I try to keep service to service communication minimal, gateway is used to "stitch" responses together using GraphQL so idea is to let the services communicate over service bus only, Auth service being the exception. I think what you are suggesting with fetching the connections aligns with my point no 1, tbh that is what I am leaning towards as well. I would prefer to keep it out of the the token but perhaps enrich the request/header itself where possible, otherwise fallback to point 2. Still not 100% sure

Comment: Actually I don't know the number of request and data etc. but I would suggest going with second one. Because it seems to me a validation for an operation for which you need answer from connection service.

Comment: This situation can be reduced to the general task — how to organize access to a resource in microservice-based application that is called frequently, taking aside that it's for authorization. Maybe it will be even better for understanding to put it that way. And organizing access to frequently called service is pretty easy, the possible solutions are: 1) service bus (asynchronous communication), 2) caching, 3) scale-up instance-wise with data partitioning by a key. No “single” correct solution. Personally, picking one, I would go for the most simple and maintainable approach.

Comment: @RVid I have the same doubt. What did you end up doing?